# How to remove overlapping bar graph count labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I made a stacked bar plot to display some results and the two right bar data labels are just an overlapping mess, but the other two are fine.

I'd be fine just omitting the two right bar's labels to make it look better, or if anyone has any recommendations for a better solution I'm all ears, thanks in advance!

Below is my code for the graph, along with the graph output.

```
p11 <- Hand_Qs %>%
  filter(Find != "NA") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Find, fill=Hand)) +
geom_bar(alpha=0.5) +
labs(title = "",
       x = "",
       y = "Count",
       size = "") +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
scale_fill_manual(values = c("1st" = "Yellow",
                                 "2nd" = "Blue",
                                 "3rd" = "Green",
                                 "4th" = "Red")) +
geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = after_stat(count)), position = position_stack(0.5), size=7)

ggplotly(p11)
```

The two bars on the right just have mashed up labels, but the other two are fine.

[image]

I tried using `check_overlap=TRUE` in the geom_text line and it didn't change anything.

I also tried adding `label = ifelse(Find %in% c("3rd", "4th")))` and it didn't do anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could display a blank if the value is below a threshold:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(gear, fill = factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar() +
  geom_text(stat = "count", 
            aes(label = if_else(after_stat(count) < 2, "", 
                                as.character(after_stat(count)))),
            position = position_stack(0.5), size=7)
```

(note, `if_else` is from `dplyr` so either that or `tidyverse` would need to be loaded. Base R `ifelse` would be a drop-in replacement here, but I prefer `if_else` for enforcing type consistency between the true and false terms.)

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much! I don't have much experience with if_else statements in Rstudio so this is super helpful!